# Как на java android сделать анимацию элемента фона кнопки при нажатии на нее?

Tags: java, android, android-animation

При событии ACTION_DOWN как сделать чтобы элемент item в файле hamburger.xml поворачивался на 45 градусов?

Запускаю проект на minSdk 21 (Android 5.0.2)

Пробовал програмно добавить в MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN код задания атрибута fromDegrees

```
        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hamburger);
        LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) drawable;
        Drawable layer = layerDrawable.getDrawable(0);
        RotateDrawable rotateDrawable = (RotateDrawable) layer;
        rotateDrawable.setFromDegrees(45);
```

но с фоном кнопки ничего не происходит.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private Button buttonHamburger;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

           buttonHamburger = findViewById(R.id.buttonHamburger);
           View.OnTouchListener onTouchHamburger = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                         //TODO rotate android:id="@+id/first_item"
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
        buttonHamburger.setOnTouchListener(onTouchHamburger);

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ACACAC"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonHamburger"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/hamburger"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

hamburger.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="2dp"
        android:bottom="24dp">
        <rotate
            android:id="@+id/first_item"
            android:fromDegrees="0"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <size
                    android:width="30dp"
                    android:height="2dp" />
                <solid android:color="#B2636363" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```